# How to fix the row value mapping Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting the error out of range object[,]

```
string MissingCompanies="";
        List<string> cmp = new List<string>();
        cmp = sr.CompanyCode();
        int count=0;
        if (DataRange!=null)
        {
            while (DataRange != null)
            {
                string code;
                bool match;
                match = false;
                code = cmp[count]; //getting error here**
                for (int dr = 1; dr <= DataRange.GetUpperBound(0); dr++)
                {
                    if (code.Equals(DataRange[dr, 1]))
                    {
                        match = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                count++;
                if (!match)
                {
                    MissingCompanies = MissingCompanies + "," + code;
                }
```

I'm getting error: code=cmp[count] -- index has out of range.

I'd be grateful for any help with this.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Eric Lippert has some [super advice](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Is this is your complete code? Some seem to be missing.